# Calculating the distance between characters

Tags: regex, string, parsing, ocr

Problem: I have a large number of scanned documents that are linked to the wrong records in a database. Each image has the correct ID on it somewhere that says where it belongs in the db.

I.E. A DB row could be:

```
| user_id | img_id | img_loc |
|  1      |   1    | /img.jpg|
```

img.jpg would have the `user_id` (1) on the image somewhere.

Method/Solution: Loop through the database. Pull the image text in to a variable with OCR and check if `user_id` is found anywhere in the variable. If not, flag the record/image in a log, if so do nothing and move on.

My example is simple, in the real world I have a guarantee that user_id wouldn't accidentally show up on the wrong form (it is of a specific format that has its own significance)

Right now it is working. However, it is incredibly strict. If you've worked with OCR you understand how fickle it can be. Sometimes a 7 = 1 or a 9 = 7, etc. The result is a large number of false positives. Especially among images with low quality scans.

I've addressed some of the image quality issues with some processing on my side - increase image size, adjust the black/white threshold and had satisfying results. I'd like to add the ability for the prog to recognize, for example, that "81**7**23103" is not very far from "81**9**23103"

The only way I know how to do that is to check for strings >= to the length of what I'm looking for. Calculate the distance between each character, calc an average and give it a limit on what is a good average.

Some examples:

Ex 1

```
81723103 - Looking for this
81923103 - Found this
-------- 
00200000 - distances between characters

0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 2

2/8 = .25 (pretty good match. 0 = perfect)
```

Ex 2

```
81723103 - Looking 
81158988 - Found
--------
00635885 - distances

0 + 0 + 6 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 8 + 5 = 35

35/8 = 4.375 (Not a very good match. 9 = worst)
```

This way I can tell it "Flag the bottom 30% only" and dump anything with an average distance > 6.

I figure I'm reinventing the wheel and wanted to share this for feedback. I see a huge increase in run time and a performance hit doing all these string operations over what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Very admirable effort and methodology.  Because this process is so dependent on a single character at times, one thing I would do for myself would be to use as high quality OCR technology as possible.  What OCR technology from what company are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Unfortunately I cannot control the scanner tech. These are mostly historical (Present and older) medical docs I have permission to work with. 

Most modern healthcare related scans come at very high resolution/quality. The downfall is the dispersement. There are so many different caregivers who have their own formats. 

I think I'm going to try a divide and conquer. Do two searchs, each one for a different half of the identifier and then get a scoring system for each image based on the accuracy of the hit.

Comment: So you are saying you cannot affect OCR as it happens, and you can only work with post-OCR data.  I am very interested is successful data cleanup/analysis algorithms, so please keep me updated (via this thread) how your implementation goes and what results you are able to achieve.